# Writing file in matlab with fprintf and dlmwrite in loop

Tags: matlab, loops, printf

I'm trying to get a loop to write headers between matrices to a .txt file from matlab.

Example code:

```
filename = 'sampleXLS.dat';
datfile = fopen(filename,'w');

header = 'Header \n';
mat1 = [1,2,3;4,5,6]; 
mat2 = [7,8;9,10];
mat3 = [11;12;13];

mats = {mat1,mat2,mat3};
for iter = 1:length(mats)
   data = mats{iter}
   fprintf(datfile, header);
   dlmwrite(filename, data,'-append','delimiter',' ','precision', '%f');
end
```

I want

```
Header
1 2 3
4 5 6 
Header
7 8
9 10
Header 
11
12
13
```

I am getting

```
Header
Header
Header
 3
4 5 6 
7 8
9 10
11
12
13
```

Note the missing 1 and 2, when I step though the file in debug mode it is inserting and replacing the numbers with the headers as it goes along.

Is there a way to tell fprintf to append?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening a file handle, this handle has a state which includes the current position. Check `fopen(fileID)` for details.

You have to set your file handle to write at the end of file using `fseek(datfile, 0, 'eof');`, otherwise you continue writing where you stopped before.

```
filename = 'sampleXLS.dat';
datfile = fopen(filename,'w');

header = 'Header \n';
mat1 = [1,2,3;4,5,6]; 
mat2 = [7,8;9,10];
mat3 = [11;12;13];

mats = {mat1,mat2,mat3};
for iter = 1:length(mats)

   data = mats{iter};
   fseek(datfile, 0, 'eof');
   fprintf(datfile, header);

   dlmwrite(filename, data,'-append','delimiter',' ','precision', '%f');
end
```

Alternatively you can open your file using `a` instead of `w` which only allows to append at the end.

```
filename = 'sampleXLS.dat';
datfile = fopen(filename,'a');

header = 'Header \n';
mat1 = [1,2,3;4,5,6]; 
mat2 = [7,8;9,10];
mat3 = [11;12;13];

mats = {mat1,mat2,mat3};
for iter = 1:length(mats)

   data = mats{iter};
   fprintf(datfile, header);

   dlmwrite(filename, data,'-append','delimiter',' ','precision', '%f');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/142835-writing-file-in-matlab-with-fprintf-and-dlmwrite-in-loop#answer_145912